# Write heartbeat metric to backend store using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

There is a program using ASP.NET Core - Startup Class using the code structure as below.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ABCStoreStatsDProvider metricProvider = ...
    services.AddSingleton<IMetricsProvider, ABCStoreStatsDProvider>(provider => metricProvider);
    // metricProvider.emitMetric(1)
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    ....
}
```

The metricProvider above has a method to send metric to the ABCStore - emitMetric(), I would like to send a metric like a heartbeat metric to the ABCStore every 1min so that I can monitor if the pipeline sending metrics to ABCStore is working fine. I am new to the ASP.NET Core and the Startup Class. I would like to know what is the best way to do it and where to write such code(like in ConfigureServices or Configure function or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use work service to achieve your requirement.

You could follow this Timed background tasks to send the request by times:

```
 public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks).